# Display div on a specific date (or range)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that I want to only be displayed for 3 specific days at a certain time of day. Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{var pDate = new Date();
 var pHour = pDate.getHours();
 if 
   ((pHour >= 10) && (pHour < 17)) 
   {
   $(".button5").show();
  }
});
```

It works for displaying the button during a specified time frame(10-17), but how do I add limitations of Month and Day?

Comment: Have a look at this [javascript date reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), this will give you all the info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for getMonth() and getDay() on the date object.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
 var pDate = new Date();
 var pHour = pDate.getHours();
 var pMonth = pDate.getMonth();
 var pDay = pDate.getDay();

 if 
   // show only the first month and first day between 10 and 17 hours of the day
   ((pHour >= 10) && (pHour < 17)  && pMonth == 1 && pDay == 1) 
   {
   $(".button5").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was doing the same thing, but it didn't work because I used "=" instead of "==" (duh). Also, I had to change getDay to getDate since getDay refers to the day of the week, not the month. Thanks again for your help!